# Can we increase number of topics and subscriptions in a google console project?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-console-developer

I am using google cloud pub/sub for receiving the push notifications of any gmail user by setting a watch on the concerned users mailbox. I am able to do that. I am creating a one topic per user in my google console project and also creating one subscription per topic. As per my knowledge we cannot make more than 10,000 topics and subscriptions in one project(GCP). My question is that can we increase this limit. I want to increase it to 100k or 10 million. Is it possible. If yes kindly suggest some resources or references, where I can read about it.

Comment: I do not see a method to increase the quota or limits for Pub/Sub for topics or subscriptions. If you go to the Google Cloud Console -> IAM & admin -> Quotas, the number for topics or subscriptions is not there to edit (editing means to request an increase). If you have paid support open a support ticket. The number 10,000 sounds arbitrary, so maybe it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, the 10,000 topics and subscriptions limit cannot be increased. It is a dimension we'd like to scale up at some point, but for now, this is not a quota for which one can request an increase.